# Google reCAPTCHA returning incorrect json response

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have a form which has Google's reCAPTCHA. But I am having trouble with the json format returned by it: In the documentation,

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api-request :

```
{
 "success": true|false,
 "challenge_ts": timestamp,  // timestamp of the challenge load (ISO format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ)
 "hostname": string,         // the hostname of the site where the reCAPTCHA was solved
 "error-codes": [...]        // optional
}
```

But I am getting this response:

```
{
 "success": true,
 "challenge_ts": "2016-06-13T06:46:40Z",
 "hostname": "devs.mysite.com.au"
} {"success":false,"errors":[null]}'
```

Resulting some error . My code is:

```
$is_valid = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$fields = array(
    'secret' => 'mysecretcode',
    'response' => $is_valid,
    'remoteip', ''
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Am i doing something wrong? Because that is not the response format that I am expecting

Comment: What exactly is different from what you are expecting? You are getting the "challenge_ts" back as a timestamp. Same for the other arguments.

Comment: Hi. It's not the challenge_ts. Look at the response there's another { } block in it which should't be there?

Comment: Hi., already solved the issue. I didn't notice that there are some code conflicting it.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37783452/edit) to reflect this fact

Answer (score 0):

The json output from the Google API is as expected. I am not too versed in json, though I expect the `[...]` for the `error-codes` argument specifies that it contain anything:

```
 "error-codes": [...]
```

What it returns is a json object (that is what the curly braces mean, see [the json specification](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html)). In fact, it returns an object with two properties: `success` and `errors`:

```
{"success":false,"errors":[null]}'
```